# Quickest way to reference a Wordpress code snippet

Tags: php, wordpress, function

This question is about tidying up code and better management of said code butI'm a complete novice when it comes to PHP so would appreciate a little help.

I have this code:

```
<?php
            $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()); // gets the post thumbnail ID

            $args = array(
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'orderby' => 'rand',
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                'post_status' => null,
                'numberposts' => 1,
                'exclude' => $thumb_id
            );

            $attachments = get_posts($args);
            if ($attachments) {
                foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                    echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'full', false);
                }
            }
        ?>
```

What it does isn't important for reference, the above code gets random images from a Wordpress post randomly generates one of them in a DIV. I want this functionality across many templates but I don't want to cram my PHP files with it as my files will get messy and inefficiently large.

2 questions.

1. Do I need to change the code above in order to put it within functions.php?
2. How can I reference the above code (that will be within my functions.php) using a short one liner that I can reuse across many different templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. You need to get out the `<?php` and `?>` if you already put your code inside those tags**

example  functions.php:

```
<?php
    blah blah
    ....


    // your code here

        $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()); // gets the post thumbnail ID

        $args = array(
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'post_status' => null,
            'numberposts' => 1,
            'exclude' => $thumb_id
        );

        $attachments = get_posts($args);
        if ($attachments) {
            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'full', false);
            }
        }
// be careful, only one "?>" in the file, no nested "<?php ?>" blocks

?>
```

**2. Use [include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), include_once(), require() or require_once()** and save your function in another file, so you can reference that file.

random_img.php

```
<?php
        $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()); // gets the post thumbnail ID

        $args = array(
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'post_status' => null,
            'numberposts' => 1,
            'exclude' => $thumb_id
        );

        $attachments = get_posts($args);
        if ($attachments) {
            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'full', false);
            }
        }
?>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
    blah blah
    .... 

    include ("random_img.php")
?>
```

Comment: You should use include("random_img.php") in the place of your template where you want to put those random images.

Comment: As I'm a complete novice with all this (please forgive if this is a basic question), is there a reason why I have to include the same code within my functions.php file AND create a new PHP file that I include into my templates? Could I not do one or the other?

Comment: No problem, sorry if I didn't explained better. Number 1. was a response to your numer 1 question, and the 2 was the answer of your second question. You could use one or the other.
I recommend you to put that code (or the include) inside your template (header.php, post.php, etc.. where you want it), not in the functions file. But you try it. I just limited myself to answer the questions you made. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may like to try putting the snippet in to a function, inside `functions.php`, and passing it a few parameters, allowing the usage to be more flexible.

Untested, but this takes an array of options, and overwrites the default values (e.g for changing the `order` or `orderby` etc on a per-use basis). As an optional parameter you can pass a `post_id`, in case you want to query a post that *isn't* the current one.

It also `returns` an array of rather than outputs them directly, which can be seen as the preferred way of working with functions.

```
// functions.php

function get_random_post_image($options=array(), $post_id=NULL) {
    if($post_id != NULL) :
        $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id); 
    else :
        $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID());        
    endif;

    $default_args = array(
           'order' => 'ASC',
           'orderby' => 'rand',
           'post_type' => 'attachment',
           'post_parent' => $post->ID,
           'post_mime_type' => 'image',
           'post_status' => null,
           'numberposts' => 1,
           'exclude' => $thumb_id
         );

    // merge custom options
    $args = array_merge($default_args, $options);


    $attachments = get_posts($args);
            if ($attachments) {
                $images = array();
                foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                    $images[] = wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'full', false);
                }
                return $images;
            }
            return false; // or, return default image/placeholder
}





// and within your template/posts:
if(function_exists('get_random_post_image')) :
    $images = get_random_post_image(array('order'=>'DESC')); // overwrite `ASC`
    if($images) :
        foreach($images as $img) {
            echo '<div class="post-img"> ' . $img . '</div>';
        }
    else :
       echo 'No images!';
    endif;
endif;
```

not perfect; but you could extend it easily enough.